# jQuery - toggleClass() highlights <tr> borders in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, hover, toggleclass

Ran into a problem that has stumped me. I want the border of a row in a table to change colors when a user hovers the cursor over them.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.song', function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('highlightRow');
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<table border="1" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;">
    <tr class="song"><td>test1</td></tr>
    <tr class="song"><td>test2</td></tr>
    <tr class="song"><td>test2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css class:

```
.highlightRow
{
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome. In Firefox the cursor changes to a pointer so it is toggling the class, but the borders never change colors. I created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5a9k2/7/) for it and it works fine. Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't be working in Firefox?

**EDIT: ANSWER**
Thanks to the answer below I realized that TR's cannot have borders. That being said I needed to keep it working with dynamic elements and wanted to highlight every  in the row, not just the one hovered over, so my final JS that worked is:

```
$(document).on('hover', 'tr.song', function()
{
    $(this).children().toggleClass('highlightRow');
});
```

Comment: It's possible that another class is overriding this one. Do you have any other styles which may be effecting it? Specifically `border:none;`? If you have FireBug installed on FireFox, this should make it easier to find out.

Comment: It works for me in FF 3.6.24.  A red border appears when I hover, disappears when I move away.

Comment: @MattAsbury, FireBug is an awesome tool thanks for the tip. I looked through my css, I don't have any styles that would be conflicting. The only thing I could see was that I have the actual table's border property set to be 1. I edited my original code to show.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me in Firefox 9 betas.  What Firefox version were you testing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders cannot be applied to "tr", try the "td" instead.

**EDIT**

Replace your jQuery code with:

```
$("tr.song td").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("highlightRow");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("highlightRow");        
});
```

Comment: I tried `$(this > td).toggleClass('highlightRow');`, which should get all the td's of the row hovered on. This doesn't change the cursor or class for me.

Comment: Try this: $('.song td').hover(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlightRow');
        });

Comment: See example I added to my answer

Comment: @superjaz1, I was originally planning on using .hover(), but in my actual project the elements are dynamically loaded with ajax and so the function wouldn't work on the new elements. 

BUT, this did work on the original elements in Firefox. YAY!

BUT, it only highlights the individual td...how could I highlight all td's in the row?

Comment: Got it!

I kept it as the .on() handler to work with dynamic elements, but my problem before was like what you said, tr's can't have borders. This is the final code that worked:
`$(document).on('hover', 'tr.song', function()
{
    $(this).children().toggleClass('highlightRow');
});`

Comment: Uh...  `<tr>` can have borders just fine in the collapsed border model, which `border="1"` happens to trigger.

Comment: Yes it can be applied, but it's not cross browser so it's not recommended. You'll find it's not supported in IE6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your border css should be:
border: 2px solid red;

From: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp
When using the border property, the order of the values are:

```
border-width
border-style
border-color
```

It does not matter if one of the values above are missing (although, border-style is required), as long as the rest are in the specified order.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Unfortunately I seem to still be having the same problem after making the fix.

Comment: @CHawk I noticed that you updated your css above. It looks like you removed the style value for the border. You need to have the style on there.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that was the only required style value. Thank you for the correct, but again, didn't fix the problem :/

Comment: Actually, per spec the order of values here doesn't matter.  `border: solid red 2px` should work just fine, and does in browsers last I checked.  In general, the w3shools website has lots and lots of inaccurracies, which they resolutely refuse to fix.